# Pink textures when changing textures of object

Tags: texturing

Pink textures when applying image to object. Absolute or relative path doesn't work. Find missing filed doesn't work too. I am 100% sure that textures exist and on the right path.

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Since you are 100% sure, what are we supposed to say? The only thing I can see is in the top screenshot, there is no path in front of the texture name. In the bottom screenshot, there is a texture with the matching name. But I have no idea if the file path is the same so that the texture can be found.

Comment: Hi Vlad. Can you try setting in your material the Base Color >> Color Space to sRGB? It is odd that it shows as a blank option. This could be due to a broken or invalid image file. If that's the case resave your image file or try with different image format.